# Error :Invalid table alias or column reference while using map in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am executing the below hive query :

```
create or replace view test.hosp as 
select
p.hosp_id,
p.hosp_name,
max(case when `p.my_map[1].id`  is NULL then 1 else 0 end  ) as hos_main_id
from
arch.hospital
group by
p.hosp_id,
p.hosp_name,
p.my_map[1].id;

Error :Invalid table alias or column reference 'p.my_map[1].id'.
```

there is a map names `my_map<int,struct<name,id:bigint>>` , then why am I still getting the error saying :

```
Error :Invalid table alias or column reference 'p.my_map[1].id'.
```

Any help is appreciated .How to select the struct value inside a map then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined the `p` alias

should be:

from
arch.hospital **p**